# LINQ where vs takewhile

Tags: .net, linq

I want to get a difference between [`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netcore-3.1) & [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) LINQ methods .I got the following data from MSDN .But It didn't make sense to me

> ```
> Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)
> ```
>
> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

> ```
> TakeWhile<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, Boolean>)
> ```
>
> Returns elements from a sequence as long as a specified condition is true.

All opinions are welcomed.

Comment: Good question - the Intellisense on TakeWhile still says "Returns elements  ... as long as a specified condition is true".  This could very well be interpreted to be the same as a Where.  The wording should rather be something like "Returns elements ... until the condition evaluates as false".

Answer (score 203, accepted):

[`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netcore-3.1) stops when the condition is false, [`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) continues and find all elements matching the condition

```
var intList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, -1, -2 };
Console.WriteLine("Where");
foreach (var i in intList.Where(x => x <= 3))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
Console.WriteLine("TakeWhile");
foreach (var i in intList.TakeWhile(x => x <= 3))
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Gives

```
Where
1
2
3
-1
-2
TakeWhile
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 39):

[`Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netcore-3.1) can examine the whole sequence looking for matches.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Where(x => x % 2 == 1)
// 1, 3, 5, 7, 9
```

[`TakeWhile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile?view=netcore-3.1) stops looking when it encounters the first non-match.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).TakeWhile(x => x % 2 == 1)
// 1
```

Comment: short and sweet, perfect answer

Answer (score 10):

Say you have an array that contains `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]`.  Now:

`var whereTest = array.Where(i => i <= 5);` will return `[1, 3, 5, 0, 2, 4]`.

`var whileTest = array.TakeWhile(i => i <= 5);` will return `[1, 3, 5]`.

Comment: I think whileTest will return only 1 depends to @David B and @Albin Sunnanbo answers

Comment: No, it will return items until the condition isn't met.  In this case, 1, 3, and 5 meet the condition (they are <= 5).

Answer (score 10):

MSDN says

[`Enumerable.TakeWhile Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.takewhile.aspx)

> Returns elements from a sequence as
>   long as a specified condition is true,
>   and then skips the remaining elements.

[`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803.aspx)

> Filters a sequence of values based on
>   a predicate.

The difference is that `Enumerable.TakeWhile` **skips the remaining elements from the first non-match whether they match the condition or not**

Answer (score 9):

While the existing answers are correct, none of them point out **why** you'd want to use TakeWhile if the results would be the same: Performance.  Suppose you have an ordered list with 2 billion items in it, and you want the ones that (probably 10 or 15 items) less than a given vallue. The Where clause will examine all 2 billion items, while the TakeWhile will stop as soon as it finds a value equal or greater than your supplied value

Answer (score 8):

The order of the sequence passed is absolutely critical with `TakeWhile`, which will terminate as soon as a predicate returns `false`, whereas `Where` will continue to evaluate the sequence beyond the first `false` value.

A common usage for `TakeWhile` is during the lazy evaluation of large, expensive, or even infinite enumerables where you may have additional knowledge about the ordering of the sequence.

e.g. Given the sequence:

```
IEnumerable<BigInteger> InfiniteSequence()
{
    BigInteger sequence = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        yield return sequence++;
    }
}
```

A `.Where` will result in an infinite loop trying to evaluate part of the enumerable:

```
var result = InfiniteSequence()
    .Where(n => n < 100)
    .Count();
```

Whereas a `.TakeWhile`, and armed with the knowledge that the enumerables is ascending, will allow the partial sequence to be evaluated:

```
var result = InfiniteSequence()
    .TakeWhile(n => n < 100)
    .Count();
```

Comment: Indeed. It's also really useful for parsing a sequence of tokens.