# What is difference between filtering: Where and takeWhile in Dart

Tags: dart

I see both of them (`where` and `takeWhile`) has the same function .. or I might miss something here!

Comment: While I guess no one has posted this question about Dart yet, I must say this distinction is not all that subtle or surprising. It should be extremely familiar to anyone who has seen the analogous (and very widely-known) [LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031726/linq-where-vs-takewhile) and [Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46850689/how-is-takewhile-different-from-filter) APIs, and probably others. And it's pretty clear in the Dart documentation, too, as @jamesdlin showed us.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [documentation for `Iterable.where`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/where.html) says:

> Returns a new lazy `Iterable` with **all** elements that satisfy the predicate `test`.

The [documentation `Iterable.takeWhile`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/takeWhile.html) says:

> Returns a lazy iterable of the **leading** elements satisfying `test`.

(emphasis added).

In other words, `Iterable.takeWhile` will stop iterating once it reaches the first item that does not satisfy the `test` callback.

A concrete example:

```dart
var list = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8];
print(list.where((x) => x.isOdd).toList()); // Prints: [1, 1, 3, 5]
print(list.takeWhile((x) => x.isOdd).toList()); // Prints: [1, 1]
```